# jQuery HTTP post not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http

I am currently working on an app and i am stuck in a very basic thing: HTTP posts. I need to pass username to the server to check if it already exists, but when i click the button which triggers the function below, nothing happens.

Server routine is fine, tested it in the browser. But am I doing something wrong here?

JavaScript:

```
$.post("http://192.168.0.5/StadtLandFluss/userManagement.php", {
    action : "checkusername",           
    username: loginName },
    function(data) {
      jSuccess();           
},'json');
```

PHP:

```
else if($action == 'checkusername'){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '$username'";
$adressen_query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($adressen_query) > 0){
    echo 'T';
}else{
    echo 'F';
}
}
```

Comment: is the click event fired at least? Could you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Yes, the event is fire. When i replace the .post with an alert I pops up, so the event is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the API that the last parameter, the dataType, is the data type expected from the server. It is not `json` but `text`. If JavaScript parses "T" or "F" to json it will throw an unexpected character error.

Try changing it to:

```
$.post("http://192.168.0.5/StadtLandFluss/userManagement.php", {
    action : "checkusername",           
    username: loginName },
    function(data) {
      jSuccess();           
},'text');
```

Comment: Thank you, i changed it. If i track down the network with my browser i see that the POST is initiated, but goes from 'pending' to 'failed'. As type it says: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", is that right? I dont know where this is coming from..

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. Please check what was sent as loginName and try your script again http://192.168.0.5/StadtLandFluss/userManagement.php?action=checkusername&username=<loginName> If the loginName looks wrong check your JavaScript code, otherwise the PHP code :-)

Answer (score -1):

what `jSuccess()` supposed to do?

Also, if I look at your code correctly, you're not even checking the result given by your `userManagement.php`. Hence, `data` from `function(data)` isn't being used.

So you should have something like:

```
jSuccess(data);
```

Or, because I dunno what that function does.

```
if(data == "T") {
    alert("Login name already exists");
}
else if(data == "F") {
    alert("Login name is available.");
}
```

Comment: jSuccess() comes from jNotify, which I am using for better notifications. It's nothing more than a success-notification for a user.